# How can I show that the sequence $a_n := p^n$ is a convergent sequence in this metric and find its limit?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Suppose $q$ is any nonzero rational number and $p$ is a fixed prime. If $q = p^k\frac{n}{m}$ for integers $n$ and $m$, neither of which has $p$ as a factor, then we define $|q|_p := p^{−k}$.
We can then, of course, define a metric $d_p(q, q') := |q − q'|_p$, and we know thanks to the strong triangle inequality that $d_p(q, q') ≤ \max\{d_p(q, q''),d_p(q'', q')\}$.

How could I use this to show that the sequence $a_n := p^n$ is a convergent sequence in this metric and find its limit?

Comment: Note that $\lvert q\rvert_p = d_p(q,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\left|p^n\right|_p = d_p\left(p^n,\,0\right)=p^{-n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|p^n\right|_p = 0$. Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|p^n - L\right|_p = 0$ for $L = 0$, which is therefore the limit of the sequence.